# Bamboo Bitbucket integration

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo, devops

Bamboo and bitbucket are two pieces from the same vendor and there should be no problem integrating those two with each other, but I have a weird situation. 
Here is what i get when trying to add bitbucket repo to my Bamboo. 
[image]See attached screenshot. 
I'm pretty sure my repo is public and I use correct bitbucket user account name.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried to add your repository in Bamboo 5.14.3.1 and it works ok, there're 2 repositories. Maybe some glitch at Bitbucket side. Can you try again?

Comment: Yeah, "glitch" (if we can call it that way) but on Bamboo side.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed BAMBOO to AWS using [Java script provided by Atlassian](https://s3.amazonaws.com/bamboo-website/bamboo-ec2-wizard/bamboo-server-ec2-wizard.jar) 
At the end it gave me a web UI links as on following screenshot [image].
It worked, however some functionality was blocked by XSRF (that is not enabled by default in Atlassian products).[image]
Works fine when I use native Bamboo URL (HTTP and port 8085) instead on HTTPS.
Be careful with that... I just wasted about 2 days trying to fix something that didn't have to be fixed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked your Bitbucket repo to Bamboo server. If not see this https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/linking-to-another-application-360677713.html

May be this can help.

Comment: Yes. I wrote in my previous comment :)